# Two or more values from function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

Im trying to get 2 values from a function. I've googled the problem, but I seem to mess up the code myself.

```
double* suurim(double arv[], int x, double *array)
{ 
    int i; 
    double temp; 
    temp = arv[0]; 
    for(i = 1; i < x; i++) // biggest 
    {
        if (arv[i] > temp)
        {
            array[0] = arv[i];
        }
    }
    for(i = 1; i < x; i++) // smallest
    {
        if (arv[i] < temp)
        {
            array[1] = arv[i];
        }
    }
    return array;
}

suurim(arv, mituArvu, array);
printf("%0.1lf\n", array[0]);
```

It does not return what it's supposed to. What is going on here?

There is an array Arv. The function should get the biggest and smallest number from the array Arv and put them to array[0] and array[1] respectively.

**edit** This i probably a duplicate, but other questions answers contain structures, which I don't want.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].  "It does not return what it's supposed to."  Which is what, exactly?

Comment: You write _It does not return what it's supposed to_. But then __what__ ist it supposed to return ?

Comment: There is an array Arv. The function should get the biggest and smallest number from the array Arv and put them to array[0] and array[1] respectively.

Comment: @KarlJoonasVolke please edit your qauestion and make that clear _there_

Comment: your sample code does not compile, so it cannot be tested anyway.  You don't explain what you expect from that code, so what can we do with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach *is* a valid way of returning more than one value back from a function. **But**:

For your maximum, you are merely returning the element of the array with the greatest index that is larger than the first element. (`temp` does not change once set). That's an algorithmic failure: e.g. your_max(1, 3, 2, 0) would return 2.

You don't actually need `temp`: you can compare `arv[i] > array[0]`, having initialised `array[0]` to `arv[0]`.

Ditto for the the computation of the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a structure:

```
typedef struct {
   double minVal;
   double maxVal;
} MIN_MAX_VALS;

MIN_MAX_VALS suurim(double arv[], int x, double *array)
{ 
    MIN_MAX_VALS xValues;
    int i; 
    double temp; 
    temp = arv[0]; 
    for(i = 1; i < x; i++) // biggest 
    {
        if (arv[i] > temp)
        {
            array[0] = arv[i];
        }
    }
    for(i = 1; i < x; i++) // smallest
    {
        if (arv[i] < temp)
        {
            array[1] = arv[i];
        }
    }
    xValues.minVal = array[0];
    xValues.maxVal = array[1];
    return xValues;
}

MIN_MAX_VALS result = suurim(arv, mituArvu, array);
printf("min:%0.1lf\n", result.minVal);
printf("max:%0.1lf\n", result.maxVal);
```

Just a way to do this. Might be optimised with pointers.

Comment: Yup. I have a feeling the OP knows that. The *real* issue is the algorithm; which you have not addressed.

Comment: I've only read *return two values out of function*. And this is one way to do this. "Algorithm" is not related with this I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this uses structures, which i said I didnt want.

Comment: Yep, I missed that.I'll leave this for someone who's looking to solve this with structures then.

Comment: Maybe soon I will learn using structures. This will come handy then, thanks.

Comment: the real issue is the op has not stated actual, verifiable, code sample, and has not stated also what's the expected output, so all you are doing is to speculate about what he could think.

Comment: 80% of the questions of SO is like that. Should we all argue about the philosophy or grammar of the questions, or shall we try helping?

Answer (score 0):

Your `temp` variable is not updated properly.

As for returning an array of parameters:

You have to pass a pointer as a reference to a previously allocated object. You do not have to return with the pointer. Values would be updated when you call the function. It is customary to pass the array size among arguments.

```
void fun( double * ret_val, int size )
{
    int idx;
    for( idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx )
    {
       ret_val[idx] = idx;
    }
}

/* invocation: */

{
     double arr[] = { -.2, .3 };
     int size = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( arr[0] );
     fun( arr, size );
}
```